# JavaScript - Repeat only javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have code that repeats my function forever, although when I make that happen the rest of my site repeats itself too. So When I try to type in text box it does not let me. And when I hover over things they blink. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
window.onload = function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    function replaceTextByImage(pattern, src) {
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(pattern, 'g'), '<span style="background-size: 100% 100%; background-image: url(\'' + src + '\');">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>');
    }

    console.log("Repeating Emoji Convert");

    // Smile 
    replaceTextByImage(':\\)', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/smile.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':smile:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/smile.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/smile.svg');

    // Tongue 
    replaceTextByImage(':P', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/tongue.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':tongue:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/tongue.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/tongue.svg');

    // Big Smile 
    replaceTextByImage(':D', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/big-smile.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':big-smile:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/big-smile.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/big-smile.svg');

    // Frown ☹ 
    replaceTextByImage(':\\(', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/frown.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':frown:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/frown.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('☹', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/frown.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/frown.svg');

    // Wink 
    replaceTextByImage(';\\)', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/wink.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':wink:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/wink.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/wink.svg');

    // Dizzy 
    replaceTextByImage('xO', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/dead.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':dizzy:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/dead.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':dead:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/dead.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/dead.svg');

    // Cry  
    replaceTextByImage(':crying:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/cry.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':cry:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/cry.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/cry.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/cry.svg');

    // Big Frown 
    replaceTextByImage('D:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/big-frown.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':big-frown:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/big-frown.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':gasp:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/big-frown.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/big-frown.svg');

    // Heart Eyes 
    replaceTextByImage(':heart-eyes:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/heart-eyes.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/heart-eyes.svg');

    // Neutral 
    replaceTextByImage(':neutral:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/neutral.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':\\|', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/neutral.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':plain:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/neutral.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/neutral.svg');

    // Raging 
    replaceTextByImage(':raging:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/raging.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':angry-red:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/raging.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/raging.svg');

    // Mad 
    replaceTextByImage(':angry:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/mad.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':mad:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/mad.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/mad.svg');

    // Teeth 
    replaceTextByImage(':teeth:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/teeth.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':wide-smile:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/teeth.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/teeth.svg');

    // Thumbs Up 
    replaceTextByImage(':thumbs-up:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/thumbs-up.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':up:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/thumbs-up.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/thumbs-up.svg');

    // Thumbs Down 
    replaceTextByImage(':thumbs-down:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/thumbs-down.svg');
    replaceTextByImage(':down:', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/thumbs-down.svg');
    replaceTextByImage('', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/thumbs-down.svg');
  }, 300);
};
```

Comment: Post your code - are you putting all of your other code inside setInterval? If so, take it out - it does not reload the whole site unless you are doing something wrong.

Comment: what's inside that `setInterval`?

Comment: @DanielH OK, I posted my full code now. It is kinda long, sorry.

Comment: @DanielH I just wanted it to be fast. Why? Is that the problem?

Comment: Why do you need to load these more than once?

Comment: You can make a mini example of this in a jsFiddle - with just 3 emojis or something... and clarify what you want to happen maybe?

Comment: @DanielH How would I do that? Could you write an answer?

Comment: @RJM I want it so that on my chat page when someone sends me a message with an emoji it updates to the emoji image. Without this it just shows `:)`

Comment: So, it's parsing a longer sentence and looking for these patterns and replacing `:heart-eyes` with an image when it's received on the other end? If so, there isn't really a reason to do it this way.

Comment: What framework are you using? What is the UI? This is not enough info.

Comment: @sheriffderek https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/list.html

Comment: Those are 'images' but not the 'User Interface' - depending on how the data is sent, the parsing could happen on that event - and not just *all the time*

Comment: Based on your other questions along this line - it may be prudent to check out a stable emoji library - https://unicodey.com/js-emoji/demo/demo.htm - since they've likely gone through all of these trials

Comment: @sheriffderek Thank you I will look at that.

Comment: @sheriffderek https://jsfiddle.net/csf30816/gxh4675j/3/

Answer (score 1):

Right now your setInterval is replacing the entire document body more than three times per second.  This is, shall we say, *somewhat problematic* from a performance point of view; every time that setInterval runs the browser has to redraw the entire web page from scratch.  It also means you can't type into a text field inside the page, because three times every second you're replacing that text field with a new one.

So don't do that.

What you're really trying to accomplish is:

> I want it so that on my chat page when someone sends me a message with an emoji it updates to the emoji image

...so instead of running your code constantly over the entire page, run it only over the contents of each new message, and only when that new message arrives, before inserting that new message into the DOM.   There's no need to be redrawing the rest of the page, because you've already done your search-and-replace against the existing messages; any substitutions that need to be done will already have been done.

How, exactly, to do that is going to depend on how you're currently receiving new message text and inserting it into the DOM, but basically the flow right now is "receive new message and insert it into the DOM as is; meanwhile constantly run search-and-replace over the entire document". It instead should be "receive new message, search-and-replace the contents of that new message as needed, insert the results into the DOM."

Comment: No. Whatever function is currently receiving new chat messages and inserting them into the DOM, just needs to run your search-and-replace over the text it's receiving before inserting it into the DOM.

Comment: OK, but what if the emoji js is linked in to the head using a `<script src=...` tag (which is how it is) then how would I do it?

Comment: By the "emoji js" do you mean the search-and-replace function you've shown here?  It doesn't make any difference how the function is linked into the document, just apply it to new message contents instead of applying it constantly on the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

Your jsFiddle is really helpful right off the bat: https://jsfiddle.net/csf30816/gxh4675j/3/

You are `innerHTML`ing the whole body. Maybe you can just watch the input and change a small specific area of the page.

Comment: OK, I see. That would be complex, but it would work.

Comment: Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: Would `document.getElementsByTagName('body').addEventListener('change', function() {` work, I think it will

Comment: I don't think that 'change' is an event for body... you could add an event to the input... the smaller the scope for observing changes - the better.

Answer (score 0):

Running an interval does NOT reload the whole document, see the [PLUNK here](https://plnkr.co/edit/XamMnd9gGfKnnN5QLxao). Your problem lies elsewhere. E.g.

```
  <body>
    <input type = "text" placeholder = "Type something" /> 
    <br />
    <div id="randomText">Random Text</div>
    <script>
      function repeatSomething() {
        var rand = Math.random();
        var randDiv = document.getElementById('randomText');
        randDiv.innerHTML  = rand; 
      }
      setInterval(repeatSomething, 1000);
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Np, I realize that this doesn't solve your problem, but it's what you asked about originally.

Answer (score 0):

You are not realoading page as F5 does it, but rather "reprinting" it, re-evaluating everything, and that's definitely not a way to go, that's terrible user experience, even less frequent. Overall, calling that function X times inside 1 loop is still bad, and as others pointed out, it'll be better to have control over incoming messages. But if for some reasons you wish to check & replace everything inside the interval, this might be a starting point: [pen](https://codepen.io/mackie_pl/pen/vmQZra)

```
    function replaceTextByImage(pattern, src) {
        var n, walk=document.createTreeWalker(document.body,NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,null,false);
  while(n=walk.nextNode()) {
    if (new RegExp(pattern).test(n.innerHTML)) n.innerHTML = n.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(pattern, 'g'), '<span style="background-size: 100% 100%; background-image: url(\'' + src + '\');">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>');
  }
    }
```

Comment: thanks. Although I am not just using the emojis for the chat, that is one reason